Can each OBS stream use a different IP?
I want to stream multiple different content streams simultaneously using OBS, but I need each stream to have a unique IP address. My goal is to make each stream appear as if it’s coming from a separate OBS instance, each with its own dedicated IP.
I’ve already set up different instances of OBS, and that part is working perfectly. Now, I’m looking for a way to assign a unique IP address to each of these instances.
I tried using Proxifier to configure specific proxies for OBS, but it didn’t work properly when I applied the proxy exclusively to OBS. After researching, I also discovered that OBS isn’t fully compatible with proxies, which might explain why this approach didn’t work.
I’m using Windows 10 and wondering if this is achievable with VPNs or proxies. For example, could I set up multiple VPN connections or use proxies to assign a unique IP to each OBS instance?

Why is the stream having a different IP address important? You only have one public IP address.

The goal is to have a unique stream for each instance of OBS, with each stream appearing to originate from a distinct IP address to ensure separation and individuality for each stream.

You would probably need several proxies to make that work since I assume you don’t have several static IP addresses

But how can I achieve this?

First of all, you need to get familiar with OBS profiles. Create one profile per instance that should use different connection. If you want to do it for multiple services, you'll need to create the copies for each of them, it's best done through Profile -> Duplicate.
Then go to File -> Settings -> Advanced -> Network and change Bind to IP to your specific connection within each newly created profile.
If your VPN/proxy isn't appearing there for whatever reason, make sure to add it through Windows network settings. Not sure how Proxifier works, but e.g. UrbanVPN appears as Local connection for me. You might need to go through the properties of the networks to find the proper names.
Lastly ensure that each instance is using the correct profile.

I managed to stream on multiple platforms simultaneously, but it wasn’t by switching profiles—it was by running multiple instances of OBS. I achieved this by adding --portable to the shortcut target, which allows each instance of OBS to operate independently.
Now, my goal is for each OBS instance to use a different IP address. However, duplicating multiple VPNs isn’t practical for me. I need the best, most cost-effective, and performance-optimized solution for achieving this setup.
Do you have any recommendations or solutions?

I don't know what setup exactly you expect without duplicating VPNs/proxies. There's definitely no "press a button to have 50 OBSes assigned to different IPs" type of solution if that's your question. It's a very unusual task that requires manual setup, possibly scripting too if you want it to be fully automated.

I understand there's no "one-click" solution for assigning multiple OBS instances to different IPs. However, if there's a way to achieve this, I'd like to know the simplest and most straightforward method. I'm okay with manual setup or basic scripting if necessary.

That's way too wide of a question then. My answer targets the OBS part as in the title. For full setup suggestions it's better to ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered although it's unlikely you'll get answers
